# How to add a method to a 3rd party library

Tags: android, github

I want to add `drawerItem.getName()` to [MaterialDrawer Library](https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer) in which the method get the name of the drawer item

How can add this method in my code to be used? or request it from the developer on GitHub?

Comment: You need to `fork` the repo, add the changes you need to add and then create a Pull Request to the original base repo and if the developer of the library finds it good enough they will merge it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your options are:

1)download the library and alter it directly, rather than using gradle.  You'll have to keep this file up to date with every new version you use of the library.

2)Fork that class under a new name and maintain it yourself.  You'll need to keep this up to date or accept that bug fixes/features will not be added.

3)You can request the maintainer of the library to add it.  Usually it helps if you do the work.  For some random library on github it may or may not ever happen, depending on if the library is abandoned or not, wether the maintainer(s) care or not, and whether they think its a good idea.

Comment: for option number one is it illegal to edit in the library as I want?

Comment: Depends on the license of the library (1 and 2 would have the same issues)

Comment: I'm sorry for this stupid question but if it is Apache V 2.0 thats normal ?

Comment: Looks like that particular library is Apache, so yes it is, but you must follow the Apache license (include the license in your package and maintain proper attribution to that code).

Comment: lastly you mean to add a dialoge for example in my running app to users?

Comment: No, you don't need to go that far. See http://www.apache.org/foundation/license-faq.html

Answer (score 2):

Actually, [BaseDrawerItem](https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer/blob/develop/library/src/main/java/com/mikepenz/materialdrawer/model/BaseDrawerItem.java) has it already and return `StringHolder` reference. You can use it as `((BaseDrawerItem)drawerItem).getName().getText()`.

Comment: Thank you also that's a great help